# Save to database inside CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring, jpa, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm trying to save an entity to a Oracle DB using `CrudRepository`, from inside a method which returns a `CompletableFuture`.

In this method I am doing a REST call to get the data, I'm processing it to an excel, then save it to the DB.

```
public CompletableFuture<byte[]> getCompletableFuture(**some parameters**)
    {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> caller.getForObjectList(**some parameters**))
                .thenApply(listWithData-> {
                    Collections.sort(**some sorting**);
                    //Inside exportExcel method I'm creating the excel and call the save method from my service which calls the repository extending CrudRepository.
                    return excelExportService.exportExcel(listWithData,**some parameters**);
                });
    }
```

I am doing `getCompletableFuture(parameters).get()` tot get the result from the CompletableFuture.

When the save method is called, my entity is populated and everything looks fine, except the fact that nothing is saved in the DB. I think this might be a Transaction problem since the code is done on a separate thread.

Comment: did you find a solution?